# How to get values from number inputs inside html table when copy/pasting into Excel or Sheets?

Tags: html, excel, clipboard

I have a html table that gets generated in a web application, 2 of these columns have their values inside number inputs.

[image: snippet of html table with number inputs]

when I copy all the table data to the clipboard it goes into the clipboard like this:

```
#   Day 
NDVI
fc
h
Kd
Fr
Kcbfull
Kcb
Pe
AW
RO
Kcmax
few
De
Ke
ETc
ETAW
ETo
fw
1   2019-07-06  0.52    0.48    3   0.72    0.81    1.041   0.79    
0.4
0
0.00    1.23    0.52    0.00    0.00    0.21    0.20    0.270   1.000
2   2019-07-07  0.77    0.79    4   0.95    0.81    1.047   1.01    
0.7
0
0.00    1.23    0.21    6.37    0.23    0.32    0.29    0.260   1.000
3   2019-07-08  0.89    0.94    4   0.99    0.81    1.047   1.04    
0.2
0
0.00    1.23    0.06    9.75    0.07    0.26    0.25    0.230   1.000
4   2019-07-09  0.73    0.73    4   0.94    0.81    1.047   0.99    
0.4
0
0.00    1.23    0.27    9.34    0.00    0.24    0.22    0.240   1.000
5   2019-07-10  0.60    0.58    4   0.87    0.81    1.047   0.93    
0.2
0
0.00    1.23    0.42    9.47    0.02    0.25    0.24    0.260   1.000
6   2019-07-11  0.81    0.84    4   0.97    0.81    1.047   1.02    
0.6
0
0.00    1.23    0.16    9.39    0.01    0.28    0.25    0.270   1.000
7   2019-07-12  0.92    0.98    4   1.00    0.81    1.047   1.04    
0.7
0
0.00    1.23    0.02    9.75    0.01    0.30    0.27    0.280   1.000
8   2019-07-13  0.76    0.78    4   0.95    0.81    1.047   1.00    
0.3
0
0.00    1.23    0.22    9.42    0.00    0.29    0.28    0.290   1.000
9   2019-07-14  0.53    0.48    3   0.72    0.81    1.041   0.80    
0.4
0
0.00    1.23    0.52    9.38    0.03    0.23    0.21    0.280   1.000
10  2019-07-15  0.69    0.69    4   0.93    0.81    1.047   0.98    
0.0
0
0.00    1.23    0.52    9.64    0.02    0.30    0.30    0.300   1.000
11  2019-07-16  0.97    1.05    4   1.00    0.81    1.047   1.05    
0.9
0
0.00    1.23    -0.05   9.75    -0.06   0.28    0.24    0.280   1.000
12  2019-07-17  0.62    0.60    4   0.90    0.81    1.047   0.96    
0.4
0
0.00    1.23    0.40    9.39    0.00    0.25    0.23    0.260   1.000
13  2019-07-18  0.62    0.60    4   0.90    0.81    1.047   0.96    
0.8
0
0.00    1.23    0.40    8.95    0.02    0.25    0.22    0.260   1.000
14  2019-07-19  0.97    1.04    4   1.00    0.81    1.047   1.05    
0.8
0
0.00    1.23    -0.04   9.75    -0.05   0.25    0.22    0.250   1.000
15  2019-07-20  0.89    0.94    4   0.99    0.81    1.047   1.04    
0.9
0
0.00    1.23    0.06    8.86    0.00    0.26    0.22    0.250   1.000
16  2019-07-21  0.99    1.06    4   1.00    0.81    1.047   1.05    
0.3
0
0.00    1.23    -0.06   9.75    -0.08   0.24    0.23    0.250   1.000
17  2019-07-22  0.68    0.68    4   0.92    0.81    1.047   0.98    
0.7
0
0.00    1.23    0.32    9.03    0.00    0.28    0.26    0.290   1.000
18  2019-07-23  0.76    0.78    4   0.95    0.81    1.047   1.00    
0.1
0
0.00    1.23    0.22    9.75    0.03    0.31    0.31    0.300   1.000
19  2019-07-24  0.65    0.63    4   0.91    0.81    1.047   0.97    
0.3
0
0.00    1.23    0.37    9.48    0.00    0.27    0.26    0.280   1.000
20  2019-07-25  0.96    1.03    4   1.00    0.81    1.047   1.05    
0.8
0
0.00    1.23    -0.03   9.75    -0.04   0.29    0.26    0.290   1.000
21  2019-07-26  0.67    0.66    4   0.92    0.81    1.047   0.98    
0.9
0
0.00    1.23    0.34    8.84    0.00    0.28    0.25    0.290   1.000
22  2019-07-27  0.91    0.96    4   0.99    0.81    1.047   1.04    
0.3
0
0.00    1.23    0.04    9.75    0.03    0.30    0.29    0.280   1.000
23  2019-07-28  0.68    0.67    4   0.92    0.81    1.047   0.98    
0.4
0
0.00    1.23    0.33    9.34    0.00    0.29    0.28    0.300   1.000
24  2019-07-29  0.97    1.04    4   1.00    0.81    1.047   1.05    
0.7
0
0.00    1.23    -0.04   9.75    -0.05   0.28    0.25    0.280   1.000
25  2019-07-30  0.74    0.75    4   0.95    0.81    1.047   1.00    
0.2
0
0.00    1.23    0.25    9.58    0.00    0.26    0.25    0.260   1.000
26  2019-07-31  0.63    0.62    4   0.91    0.81    1.047   0.96    
0.7
0
0.00    1.23    0.38    9.01    0.01    0.26    0.23    0.270   1.000
```

The values from the inputs exist in the clipboard, but they're placed on new lines, when I paste this data into excel or google sheets, the data on those new lines do not appear, they come up blank.

[image: data with some blank columns pasted into google sheet]

My question is, is there some special tag that would treat this input like plain text upon copying the table?

Comment: Give us the website link.

Comment: https://irriquest.habitatseven.work - ty